# Error connecting with hive, to a cosmos server of fiware

Tags: hadoop, fiware, fiware-cosmos

I can't connect via hive to cosmos server in PHP with:

```
 // Load this lib
  require_once __DIR__ . '/php-thrift-sql-master/ThriftSQL.phar';

  // Try out a Hive query

$usuario="user@user";
$clave="pass"; 

  $hive = new \ThriftSQL\Hive( 'cosmos.lab.fiware.org', 10000, $usuario, $clave, 1);
  $hiveTables = $hive
    ->setSasl( false ) // To turn SASL auth off, on by default
    ->connect()
    ->queryAndFetchAll( 'SHOW TABLES' );
  print_r( $hiveTables );

  // Don't forget to clear the client and close socket.
  $hive->disconnect();
```

---

```
Error produced is Thrift\Exception\TTransportException: TSocket: timed out reading 4 bytes from cosmos.lab.fiware.org:10000 in phar://C:/Users/.../php-thrift-sql-master/ThriftSQL.phar/Thrift/Transport/TSocket.php on line 274
```

I tried with other servers like storage.cosmos.lab.fiware.org and computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org. And if I put a long timeout, then the script waits forever.

Can you help me to connect with php to the hive server of cosmos?

Comment: No an expert on PHP, but I would bet for setting to true the SASL.

Comment: With true, error says: Could not perform SASL auth. in phar

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your port..write port where are you using hadoop. My is 8088.